# How to locate multiple child elements in same node for iteration loop

Tags: c++, xml, xpathnavigator

I've below xml data file with two nodes having qty more than 100,

```
<DO>
   <delivery>
    <dono>DM202422</dono>
    <custcode>M15</custcode>
    <custname>A Company</custname>
    <stockcode>ZPP56012303001</stockcode>
    <stockdesc>56012303001 DUPLEX PTD BOX</stockdesc>
    <unitprice>2.1900</unitprice>
    <qty>500</qty>
    <amount>1095.00</amount>
  </delivery>
  <delivery>
    <dono>DM202432</dono>
    <custcode>M23</custcode>
    <custname>B Company</custname>
    <stockcode>ZPP5605855V16</stockcode>
    <stockdesc>5605855 V16 PLAIN BOX</stockdesc>
    <unitprice>0.1000</unitprice>
    <qty>2000</qty>
    <amount>200.00</amount>
  </delivery>
</DO>
```

My Question here is how suppose I could display 2 child element value under each nodes by using XPathNavigator.

If let said I need to display dono and custcode in each line of iteration loop like example of dono="DM202422" and custcode="M15" under custname="A Company".

Can anyone help me to improve my below codes, it is simply display one child element and same element after I've to next child element.

```
void queryinxpath()
{

    System::Xml::XPath::XPathDocument^ doc = gcnew System::Xml::XPath::XPathDocument("C:/test.xml");

    System::Xml::XPath::XPathNavigator^ nav = doc->CreateNavigator();

    System::Xml::XPath::XPathExpression^ expr = nav->Compile("descendant::delivery[amount > 100]");

    System::Xml::XPath::XPathNodeIterator^ iterator=nav->Select(expr);

    while (iterator->MoveNext())
    {
        System::Xml::XPath::XPathNavigator^ nav_ = iterator->Current->Clone();

        nav_->MoveToChild("dono","");

        System::Console::WriteLine("DO No: {0} ",nav_->Value);

        nav_->MoveToChild("custcode","");

        System::Console::WriteLine("Customer Code : {0} ",nav_->Value);

        System::Console::WriteLine("\n");

    }


}
```

The outcome of wrong result :

DO No: DM202422

Customer Code : DM202422

My desired result:

DO No: DM202422

Customer Code : M15

Thanks in advance for anyone could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

adding nav_->MoveToParent() to the top of  nav_->MoveToChild("dono","") after each occupied navigator will solved my problems.

```
while (iterator->MoveNext())
    {
        System::Xml::XPath::XPathNavigator^ nav_ = iterator->Current->Clone();

        nav_->MoveToChild("dono","");

        System::Console::WriteLine("DO No: {0} ",nav_->Value);

        nav_->MoveToParent();
        nav_->MoveToChild("custcode","");

        System::Console::WriteLine("Customer Code : {0} ",nav_->Value);

        nav_->MoveToParent();
        nav_->MoveToChild("custname","");

        System::Console::WriteLine("Customer Name : {0} ",nav_->Value);

        System::Console::WriteLine("\n");

    }
```